# AWS Secrets manager create with KMS Key ID

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am following this documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/create-secret.html

[image]

**My problem is,whenever i try to create a new secret key it creates a  with default Encryption key**

I need custom kms-key-id, i specify the ARN. still no luck.

sample code which i have tried.

```
 aws secretsmanager create-secret 
    --name test-5 
    --secret-string file://mycreds.json  
    --region us-east-1  
    --kms-key-id arn:aws:kms:****d292
```

## Edit -1

whenever i tried with `aws secretsmanager list-secrets`

it's returning the changed value. Even i create a testlambda and

```
get_secret_value_response = client.describe_secret(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
```

get_secret_value_response is reflecting the changes. It's bug or problem in aws console ui.

Comment: Yea this seems to be an issue with the ui. I was able to reproduce this